# How to set an application to open in a certain position on the screen?

Tags: settings, window-decoration

Say I wanted an application to open its window in the center of the screen instead of some inconvenient place like the top left (I have a pretty big monitor, so I'd have to raise my head. Also, the glare from my windows bounces off there, too).

Is there something that I can edit which does this so that I won't need to drag it to the center every time I use it?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41556/how-can-i-open-two-half-screen-windows-in-a-row-without-overlapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just fire up ccsm and go to place windows > fixed windows placement

Comment: I see. That's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized/27833#27833) for an explanation.

Comment: hmmmm... I set this up and now I have this weird black window that won't close and won't move, even after I removed devilspie.

Comment: I reset reset Unity and the black window went away. Sorry, this didn't work.