# How can I make programs open on a specific monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, window-manager

I've read a bit about window managers, but I'm not sure if that's what I need or not. I'm using my Maverick laptop at work with an external monitor added and set so they don't mirror. I've used a Mac at work up until recently (although Linux at home) and admit that I've been a bit spoiled with their Spaces and app handling - you can, in the settings panel, indicate that a specific app should always open on a specific monitor. So, for example, I want my IDE to always open on the larger external monitor, while Thunderbird should always open on the small laptop screen.

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/48892/how-to-set-an-application-to-open-in-a-certain-position-on-the-screen

Comment: Interesting that this is marked as a duplicate, when the question that it's "duplicating" was asked 4 years after this one.