# How to always use a particular monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have two monitors, one is my primary work monitor where I use eclipse. Whenever I launch the application from eclipse, it creates a new window. However it always gets launched on the same monitor.

Can I convince eclipse or something to display the application on other monitor. I know I can drag, but doing it every time is waste of time.

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108654/how-to-starts-apps-always-on-primary-display) is a daemon what moves all opened windows to specified monitor, while you can blacklist eclipse to not move it self

Comment: Seems a dupe of the linked one. If you don't agree, please mention.

Comment: Its very similar to that, but slightly different use case. Application getting launched is browser. I have other instances of browser open wherever I need. I need to position only newly launched window to certain location and not go by generic application name

Comment: Seems a bit odd, since all windows were once new windows.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I see what you are saying, I guess I am trying to distinguish between the instance of browser launched and always active on my desktop vs many browser instances launched from eclipse