# How can I make new windows open on the second screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, screen, window

I would like every app to open new windows only on the second screen. By default, new windows open on the screen where the cursor is located.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Here you are: [How to start apps always on specific display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108654/how-to-start-apps-always-on-specific-display) Please ping me @myname if you need help.